# is there a way to show react-tooltip with event's content when click

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-tooltip

I am using `Fullcalendar` with `react-tooltip` component. It works properly when hover but I want the tooltip to be opened when click the event. As shown in `react-tooltip` documentation I can add buttons and show(hide) the tooltip when clicking buttons, but I can't do the same for events.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it use a prop called event for the react-toolTip
check the link for more [react-toolTip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip)

```js
   <ReactTooltip type="success" event="click" id="registerTip" place="top" effect="solid">
                  <Fullcallender/>
                </ReactTooltip>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That package is HUGE just for a tooltip.